# Image map area changed upon using plugin

Tags: javascript, html, image, plugins, imagemap

So I'm using this [image map plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-map) so that the area is fixed to the image even when I resize the window or zoom in.

I want to make my codes that when you click, it'll call the specified function. So far it works (function is called) but for some reason when I add this implementation code to my `<script>`, it alters the area to a smaller size. When I remove it, the area goes back to the original size.

```
$(function () {
            ImageMap('img[usemap]');
            //check for plugin implement
            alert("ImageMap plugin enabled");
        });
```

I'd just remove the above code because apparently the area doesn't resize when I resize my window, but this is just a sample code to test. What's weirder is that when I use the template for my actual codes (just the same codes but the image and text content changed), my image map *doesn't even work.*

Here's the full code (the changes are on the third picture on the right):

```js
            $(function () {
                ImageMap('img[usemap]');
                //check for plugin implement
                alert("ImageMap plugin enabled");
            });

            function selectASC() {
                alert("Hello");

            }
```

```css
            body {
                background-color: #CFFFE7;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #master {
                display: table;
                position: relative;

                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: 30px 70px 60px 70px;

                height: 100%;

            }

            p {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-size: 2vw;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            #diagrams {
                background-color: lightblue;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .logo-image {
                vertical-align: middle;
                display: table-cell;

            }

            .logo-image img {
                max-width: 90%;
                max-height: 90%;
            }
```

```html
<div id="master" class="container">
            <p>This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence. This is a very long sentence.</p>
            <p>
                This is a very long sentence.
                <br/> This is a very long sentence.</p>
            <div id="diagrams" class="container">
                <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                    <div class="logo-image">
                        <img id="ssc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-image">
                        <img id="msc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-image">
                        <img id="asc" src="http://www.immersion-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-placeholder-500x500.jpg" alt="Placeholder Image" usemap="#image-map"/>
                        <map name="image-map">
                            <area coords="0,0,338,338" alt="" shape="rect" title="test" href="#" onclick="selectASC()">
                        </map>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The outcomes of both my example code and actual code are different, and I'm certain my html/css codes don't affect the results since they're the same but just different image and text content.

Comment: any messages in the browser developer tools console perhaps?

Comment: Nope, sadly. :(